# One-liner to split very large directory into smaller directories on Unix

Tags: shell, unix, filesystems, wget

How do you to split a very large directory, containing potentially millions of files, into smaller directories of some custom defined maximum number of files, such as 100 per directory, on UNIX?

Bonus points if you know of a way to have `wget` download files into these subdirectories automatically. So if there are 1 million `.html` pages at the top-level path at `www.example.com`, such as

```
/1.html
/2.html
...
/1000000.html
```

and we only want 100 files per directory, it will download them to folders something like

```
./www.example.com/1-100/1.html
...
./www.example.com/999901-1000000/1000000.html
```

Only really need to be able to run the UNIX command on the folder after `wget` has downloaded the files, but if it's possible to do this with `wget` as it's downloading I'd love to know!

Comment: Are the commas necessary in the file names? They're going to make the solution a lot more complicated.

Comment: Not necessarily, but the downloaded files could technically contain anything (a lot of them contain commas, and these characters: `?,:;/% {}[]$&*^@!~` ).

Comment: Ok, now I'm confused... if your file names contain a bunch of special characters, how are you going to create the directory names? In your example, the directories contain a range of numbers... are the file names going to be of the format `{name-including-special-characters}{number}.html`?

Comment: I'm not too concerned about the special characters, I'm more just looking for _any_ answer - how about just digits and letters. Once I see how to do it in the simple case I'm sure I can figure it out from there, just looking for a push in the right direction (like what command can actually do this). The folders can also just be named `1-100`...`999901-1000000`, whatever, just as long as it chunks a large directory into smaller ones.

Answer (score 4):

Another option:

```
i=1;while read l;do mkdir $i;mv $l $((i++));done< <(ls|xargs -n100)
```

Or using `parallel`:

```
ls|parallel -n100 mkdir {#}\;mv {} {#}
```

`-n100` takes 100 arguments at a time and `{#}` is the sequence number of the job.

Comment: Neither worked for me because of permission issues, and adding `sudo` or `sudo bash` didn't help either. Might need to write it in a two line script, and then execute the script with `sudo`.

Answer (score 3):

You can run this through a couple of loops, which should do the trick (at least for the numeric part of the file name). I think that doing this as a one-liner is over-optimistic.

```
#! /bin/bash
for hundreds in {0..99}
do
    min=$(($hundreds*100+1))
    max=$(($hundreds*100+100))
    current_dir="$min-$max"
    mkdir $current_dir
    for ones_tens in {1..100}
    do
        current_file="$(($hundreds*100+$ones_tens)).html"
        #touch $current_file 
        mv $current_file $current_dir
    done
done
```

I did performance testing by first commenting out `mkdir $current_dir` and `mv $current_file $current_dir` and uncommenting `touch $current_file`. This created 10000 files (one-hundredth of your target of 1000000 files). Once the files were created, I reverted to the script as written:

```
$ time bash /tmp/test.bash 2>&1 

real        0m27.700s
user        0m26.426s
sys         0m17.653s
```

As long as you aren't moving files across file systems, the time for each `mv` command should be constant, so you should see similar or better performance. Scaling this up to a million files would give you around 27700 seconds, i.e. 46 minutes. There are several avenues for optimization, such as moving all files for a given directory in one command, or removing the inner for loop.

Doing the 'wget' to grab a million files is going to take far longer than this, and is almost certainly going to require some optimization; preserving bandwidth in http headers alone will cut down run time by hours. I don't think that a shell script is probably the right tool for that job; using a library such as WWW::Curl on cpan will be much easier to optimize.

Answer (score 3):

To make ls|parallel more practical to use, add a variable assignment to the destination dir:

```
DST=../brokenup; ls | parallel -n100 mkdir -p $DST/{#}\;cp {} $DST/{#}
```

Note: `cd <src_large_dir>` before executing.

The DST defined above will contain a copy of the current directory's files, but a maximum of 100 per subdirectory.