# Splitting a large directory into smaller ones in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have a large directory named as `application_pdf` which contains 93k files. My use-case is to split the directory into 3 smaller subdirectories (to a different location that the original large directory) containing around 30k files each. 
Can this be done directly from the commandline. 
Thanks!

Comment: What did you try? The answer is yes, it is doable on the command line (look into `find` and `awk`). BTW, are all involved file names ordinary ones, or do you have to deal with weird file names (e.g. containing spaces, control characters, strange punctuation).

Comment: I tried the explanation mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173732/one-liner-to-split-very-large-directory-into-smaller-directories-on-unix   but couldnt really follow the process.

Comment: It would help to know what the filenames (or representative group of them are) so you can either divide into subdirectories by some aspect of the name, or by modification time or just randomly splitting at 30K. What are you trying to do in that regard?

Comment: file names are varying so my attempt would be to mv for random 30k files

Comment: Then just do `cnt=0; dircnt=1; for file in "path/to/"*.pdf; [ -d "new_dir_$dircnt" ] || mkdir -p "new_dir_$dircnt"; mv "$file" "new_dir_$dircnt"; ((cnt++)); ((cnt % 30000 == 0)) && { cnt=0; ((dircnt++)); }; done` or something similar. You can also look at `split`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using bash:

```
x=("path/to/dir1" "path/to/dir2" "path/to/dir3")
c=0
for f in *
do
    mv "$f" "${x[c]}"
    c=$(( (c+1)%3 ))
done
```

Comment: Very elegant solution - I borrowed your concept of an array for mine. Thanks ;-)

Comment: the solution helped. Pretty neat.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
for x in $(ls -1 originPath/*.pdf | head -30000); do
    mv originPath/$x destinationPath/
done
```

Comment: I see what you are thinking, but you have just fallen into [**Bash Pitfall #1**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin hey man, i was wondering... could this be an acceptable way to deal with the whitespaces in filenames, what do you think?

`${ "$(ls -1 originPath/*.pdf | head -30000)"// /\\ }`

Comment: Good thought, but... You can't really use any type of *parameter expansion* on the output of a *command substitution*. To use *parameter expansion with substring replacement* you need to capture the output of the command in a *variable* first. But when dealing with multiple files, it is better to *pipe* the output to a command that will handle whatever changes you want. It looks like you are trying to change a `' '` (each space) into `'\'` (a backslash). Odd, but it's up to you. Why not `ls -1 originPath/*.pdf | sed 's/\s\s*/_/g'` to change all whitespace *sequences* to `'_`' (underscores)?

Comment: Which would change, e.g. `'this  is    a spaced up file.pdf''` to `'this_is_a_spaced_up_file.pdf'`.

Comment: I tried to use expansion substitution to replace the whitespace `' '` with backslash whitespace `'\ '` to get filenames as `"file\ name.pdf"`, it echoes just fine but you are completetly correct the newlines are not recognized correctly outside the ls subshell. So close yet so far... xD dang

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `rename` command from **Perl**, you could try it like this:

```
rename --dry-run -pe 'my @d=("dirA","dirB","dirC"); $_=$d[$N%3] . "/$_"' *.pdf
```

In case you are not that familiar with the syntax:

- -p says to create output directories, à la `mkdir -p`
- -e says to execute the following Perl snippet
- $d[$N%3] selects one of the directories in array `@d` as a function of the serially incremented counter `$N` provided to the snippet by `rename`
- The output value is passed back to `rename` by setting `$_`

Remove the `--dry-run` if it looks good. Please run on a small directory with a **copy** of 8-10 files first, and make a backup before trying on all your 93k files.

**Test**

```
touch {0,1,2,3,4,5,6}.pdf

rename --dry-run -pe 'my @d=("dirA","dirB","dirC"); $_=$d[$N%3] . "/$_"' *.pdf
'0.pdf' would be renamed to 'dirB/0.pdf'
'1.pdf' would be renamed to 'dirC/1.pdf'
'2.pdf' would be renamed to 'dirA/2.pdf'
'3.pdf' would be renamed to 'dirB/3.pdf'
'4.pdf' would be renamed to 'dirC/4.pdf'
'5.pdf' would be renamed to 'dirA/5.pdf'
'6.pdf' would be renamed to 'dirB/6.pdf'
```

---

More for my own reference, but if you don't have the **Perl** `rename` command, you could do it just in **Perl**:

```
perl -e 'use File::Copy qw(move);my @d=("dirA","dirB","dirC"); my $N=0; @files = glob("*.pdf"); foreach $f (@files){my $t=$d[$N++%3] . "/$f"; print "Moving $f to $t\n"; move $f,$t}'
```