# Bash & Mac OSX: How to group files into numbered folders in batches of 5?

Tags: bash, macos

I am on Mac Os 10.14.6 and have a directory that contains subdirectories that all contain text files. Altogether, there are many hundreds of text files.

I would like to go through the text files and group them into numbered folders, so each folder contains 5 files (they do not need to be grouped by any common factor (e.g. they do **not** need to be grouped by name or size). They just need to have 5 files in a folder)

**Example** 
*Before running script*

```
apple.txt
new york.txt
ranger.txt
london.txt
the mountains (55).txt
so wonderful - new version.txt
my life a new.txt
orange.txt
property.txt
space.txt
```

*After running script*

```
**In Folder 01**
apple.txt
new york.txt
ranger.txt
london.txt
the mountains (55).txt

**In Folder 02:**
so wonderful - new version.txt
my life a new.txt
orange.txt
property.txt
space.txt
```

(Nb, the folders are just called `01, 02, 03,` they don’t have any special names).

How would I do this?

---

**Steps I have tried**

Google around, it seems Bash would be best for this.

In Bash, you can use the `a` command to create an array to store files, allowing you to work with them. You can then loop through the files to put them in the array.

```
declare -a arrFiles
for file in cd
do
    arrFiles=("${Files[@]}" "$file")
done
```

Bash also has the `mv` command which can be used to move files into new locations.

However, I am not sure how to combine these commands to group files into batches for 5.

Please note: As long as the solution works on Mac OS terminal, then it does not need to use Bash. However, from Googling, Bash seems to be the most suited.

Comment: Wrt *As long as the solution works on Mac OS terminal, then it does not need to use Bash.*; so, is this a bash question or not? Terminal is just an emulator, it has nothing to do with the scripting language

Comment: If this is a bash question, you can populate an array with filenames and loop through it creating a new folder and moving the next 5 files into it for each turn.

Comment: @oguz ismail From my research, I think Bash would be the best way of achieving this, but if Bash is not good, then I am open to other solutions.

Comment: @oguzismail I have updated my question with the array, but I am not sure how to move on each turn?

Comment: `a` is not a command. `for f in cd` simply loops once, with the variable `f` set to the static string `cd`. Probably read a basic introduction to the language, or ask a separate question about the parts of the syntax you need help with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45930989/splitting-a-large-directory-into-smaller-ones-in-linux

Comment: @tripleee That question you linked is not the same, as that has a defined number of folders (e.g. 3). Mine has a variable number of folders. Also, I don’t understand why my question is being voted down. The one you linked to was answered even though the OP wrote no code and was effectively using StackOverflow as a code writing service.  Here I have posted a clear use case and I am trying to learn and I am getting penalized for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this bash script:

```
unset n
while IFS= read -rd '' f; do
    printf -v d '%02d' $(( (n++ + 5) / 5 ))
    [[ ! -d $d ]] && mkdir "$d"
    mv "$f" "$d/"
done < <(find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -print0)
```

`(( (n++ + 5) / 5 ))` is modulo arithmetic to get numbers `1` when `n` is `0..4`, or get `2` when `n` is `5..9` etc.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to remove the word folder, so the folders are just called `01`, `02`, `03` (so the numbers are two digits?)